# Block tools menu in wp-admin?

Tags: wp-admin

I'm using this code to remove tools from wp-admin menu. But how do I block the access to mydomain.com/wp-admin/tools.php since I still can visit it by typing in the URL?

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
remove_menu_page('tools.php');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example add this:

```
foreach( array( 'tools', 'import', 'export' ) as $x )
{
    add_action( "load-{$x}.php", function() 
    { 
        if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
            wp_die( __( 'No access!' ) );
    } );
}
```

to restrict access to the `{tools,import,export}.php` pages for non-admins.